# Can you turn around in Circus Imperium?

Tags: circus-imperium

In FASA's **Circus Imperium**, are you allowed to turn your chariot around on an oval track?

One of the tactics suggested during a previous game was for a player who has no chance of winning to turn around and kamikaze the lead player with a head on crash. The logic being, is your loss is worth my death.

There are rules for head on collisions when we have them with the figure-8 track. Would you allow the player to turn around and go the wrong way down the track? Is a full turn penalty enough? Having to start/finish in the inside/outside lane?

Comment: I don't think there is any reason to add more griefing to a game.  Why is the person in 2nd any more deserving of the win?

Comment: It may be that we play too many other "screw your neighbour" games (Munchkin, etc.); or perhaps it is our group's way of showing the love. But when someone has won to many games in a row, or has started celebrating to early. We've teamed up before to when someone was nearly a full lap ahead of the pack (it failed, but it was a lot of fun). It's kind of the "crabs in the bucket mentality". Why would anyone intentionally crash into another player (figure-8 or oval) track.

Comment: I don't think you would intentionally, but you might be forced to depending where everyone else is positioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally the rule of play is **no, you cannot turn your chariot away from the forward path of the track**. You *can* plot to ram in the figure 8 and are encouraged to damage the other chariots to the point of destruction.

Additionally, the ruling class watching would scream for a laser show to cut you and your beasts down if you tried a turnabout, well before your collision could occur...  Give the boys in the corner seats their cheers by smashing into the wall, leaping into the other player's chariot and kicking them into the oncoming frenzy.

Comment: Can you point to a rule, designer comment, FAQ, or suchlike to support this?  (I'm not disagreeing; I don't know the game.  But if you can add a source your answer will be stronger.)